# How do I define a message body filter policy for SNS in CDK?

Tags: amazon-sns

Per the title, I want to know how to use CDK to define a [payload filter policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html) for a message body in CDK?

I've tried to get this to work correctly in TypeScript, but am struggling to get it to compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Examples for this are lacking but here is an example on how to define a OR policy that looks at the `event` field in the message body and only accepts messages where the value is either `ASSIGNED` or `CANCELLED`:

```
myTopic.addSubscription(
  new SqsSubscription(myQueue, {
    filterPolicyWithMessageBody: {
      event: sns.FilterOrPolicy.filter(
        sns.SubscriptionFilter.stringFilter({
          allowlist: [
            'ASSIGNED',
            'CANCELLED',
          ],
        })
      ),
    },
  })
)
```